# ArrayList, adding with CharAt

Tags: java, arraylist

I let user to type input and then I'm trying to add all characters that comes right after Space in the input. So I coded as follows;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    capitalizeFirstLetters(input);

public static void capitalizeFirstLetters(String input) {

    ArrayList<String> cap = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i =0; i< input.length(); i++) {
        if(input.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            cap.add(input.charAt(i+1));  //this is where an error occurs and won't add the '(input.charAt(i+1))'.
```

How could I make it work?

Thank you!!

Comment: change your arraylist usage as `ArrayList<Character> cap = new ArrayList<Character>();` because you are trying to add that list a character and not a String

Answer (score 1):

It shows an error because you are trying to add a `char` to an ArrayList which is supposed to hold objects of type `String`

Do this instead ,

`cap.add( Character.toString(input.charAt(i + 1)));`

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred because you were trying to add  Character to a String list.
You can simplify your solution in the following ways

```
public static void capitalizeFirstLetters(String input) {

        List<Character> collect = Arrays.stream(input.split(" "))
                .map(x -> x.charAt(0))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```